# deleteCharactersInRange: Range or index out of bounds'

Tags: ios, ios7

This one works on the ios simulator but not on my iphone device. Why?

```
NSMutableString *categoryList = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSArray *category in self.storedCategories) {
    [categoryList appendString:[category valueForKey:@"value"]];
    [categoryList appendString:@","];
}
[categoryList deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([categoryList length]-1, 1)]
```

---

```
2014-01-17 19:41:58.572 someapp[14586:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString deleteCharactersInRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2de38f4b 0x382796af 0x2de38e8d 0x2ddfd88f 0x98419 0x305e0713 0x305e06b3 0x305e0691 0x305cc11f 0x305e0107 0x305dfdd9 0x305dae65 0x305b079d 0x305aefa3 0x2de04183 0x2de03653 0x2de01e47 0x2dd6cc27 0x2dd6ca0b 0x32a93283 0x30610049 0x995ed 0x38781ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `self.storedCategories` is nil or empty then you will try to remove a character from an empty string. You should always check the string length before trimming / deleting.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem interesting that your app crashes on an actual device and not on the simulator. I would suggest that you actually redesign your implementation by replacing

```
[categoryList appendString:@","];
```

with this:

```
if(![[self.storedCategories lastObject] isEqual:category]) {
    [categoryList appendString:@","];
}
```

This will prevent a comma from being added at the end (which is what I assume that you're trying to do with the deleteCharactersInRange: method), and it will also take care of the case where there are no objects in self.storedCategories and you try to delete a character from an empty string!